# batch script to prompt the user twice and multiply the inputs

Tags: batch-file

My assignment is to make a script that can count the price of ice cream balls.

The user is prompted to enter the number of ice cream balls and then the script shows the ice cream price. Four options to choose 1, 2, 3 or 4 balls that cost 10, 20, 30 or 40.

Comment: `set /?` - see `/a` and `/p` options.

Comment: Do your own assignment, if you need help with it speak to your tutor; _(that's the best way of ensuring you receive the best help)_.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free script writing service. Show some initiative and actually _try_ to find an answer. As @Stephan said, `set /p` and `set /a` are going to be your friends. Please show some code that you're having trouble with at the very least, and we may help you. Please read up on how to [ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

LOL.

```
@echo off
set /P NUM_BALLS="How many ice cream balls?"
echo %NUM_BALLS%0
```